# Is there any museum of early modern computing technology in Taiwan?

Tags: electronic-items, taiwan, museums, history

I'm wondering if anywhere in Taiwan there is a computer museum or technology museum at least partially dedicated to the early development of modern local computing technology.

I'm interested in the early local development, from the first transistors up to about 1995.

I'm not interested in museums that have only old stuff from the west, or museums that only have modern local stuff from the last 20 years or so.

I am interested in how Taiwan got involved in manufacturing electronics for western companies, or intended for western markets.

I am interested in Taiwanese clones of western or Japanese tech, hacks of foreign tech to support the Chinese language, or actually any of the earliest machines with digital support for the Chinese language.

(I don't mind if it's small or hard to get to.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll find much. Taiwan started by manufacturing low-end electronic radios and components for that kind of application. Many (probably most) of the electronics books and manuals available in Taiwan were bootlegged copies with poor bindings, sold in tiny shops.

From memory, the IC industry started by a government-funded initiative (Electronic Research and Service Organization) that made so-so copies of Western parts that then was spun off into maybe half a dozen semiconductor companies such as UMC which were partially non-government funded.

One of those spin-offs (I believe from the early 1980s) is the semiconductor foundry TSMC, which has a "[Museum of Innovation](https://www.tsmcmoi.com/en)" in Hsinchu. But I would not expect any museums to cover the somewhat seedy original days of copying, and rather to concentrate on the modern era of impressive innovations and vast investments.